# Convergence of $\sum\log\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find whether the following sum converges or diverges:
$$
\log{2} + \log\left(1-\frac{1}{2^p}\right) + \log\left(1+\frac{1}{3^p}\right) + \ldots = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\right)
$$
I have discovered that this series converge for $p\geq 1$, diverge for $p\leq 0$, and also diverges for $p = \frac{1}{2}$.

My guess is that the series diverge for $0<p<1$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597060/conditional-convergence-of-sum-n-2-infty-ln-left1-frac-1nnp-rig?lq=1), the ones that answered claimed that it's convergent for $0<p\leq 1$, which is wrong for $p=\frac{1}{2}$, and also one of the answers used the limit comparison test, which is invalid for series with mixed-sign terms.

I have tried to use the Taylor series, but I am not familiar with any theorem stating that I can switch the order of infinite sums. Also, the ratio test is inconclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**
Using Taylor expansions *(not quite series, only the local, asymptotic version to few terms)*: when $n\to \infty$, for $p > 0$,
$$
 -\ln\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\right)
= \frac{(-1)^n}{n^p} + \frac{1}{2n^{2p}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{2p}}\right)
$$
The first term is the general term of a (conditionally) convergent series by the alternating series criterion. The second, $$
b_n = \frac{1}{2n^{2p}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{2p}}\right)
$$
is the general term of a series that will be (absolutely) convergent for $2p > 1$ by the comparison test and divergent otherwise (comparing to the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{2p}}$).

So, to sum up:

- if $p>\frac{1}{2}$, the series converges as the sum of a (conditionally) convergent and an (absolutely) convergent series.
- if $0 < p \leq \frac{1}{2}$, the series diverges as the sum of a (conditionally) convergent and a *divergent* series.

---

**Method 2:** Still Taylor expansion, *(but in a different fashion)*.
Write $S_{N} = \sum_{n=1}^N \ln\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\right)$, for $N\geq 1$.
First, since $S_{2N+1} - S_{2N} = \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{(2N+1)^p}\right) \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} 0$, it is sufficient to study the convergence of $(S_{2N})_N$.

Let us group the terms by consecutive pairs:
$$\begin{align}
S_{2N} &= \sum_{n=1}^N \left(
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^p}\right)+\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{(2n)^p}\right) \right)
\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N 
\ln\left(\left( 1+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^p}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{(2n)^p}\right) \right)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N 
\ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^p}-\frac{1}{(2n)^p}-\frac{1}{(2n\cdot(2n-1))^p} \right)
\end{align}$$
Now, this is unpleasant, but to apply theorems of comparisons to this $S_{2N}$, we can do a Taylor expansion (to order 2 or so) of what is inside the logarithm, then do a first-order expansion of the logarithm itself:
$$
 1+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^p}-\frac{1}{(2n)^p}-\frac{1}{(2n\cdot(2n-1))^p}
= 1-\frac{1}{(2n)^{2p}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{2p}}\right)
$$
so
$$
 \ln\left( 1+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^p}-\frac{1}{(2n)^p}-\frac{1}{(2n\cdot(2n-1))^p}\right)
= -\frac{1}{(2n)^{2p}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{2p}}\right)
$$
and by theorems of comparison (again with a $p$-series) we get that $(S_{2N})_N$ converges iff $2p > 1$.

Comment: Why not include p = 1/2?

Comment: By mistake -- I forgot; I'll add it (currently adding an alternative approach as well). Thanks!

Comment: @ClementC.Great approach. I do have one question though. For $p=\frac{1}{2}$, I was forced to expand $\ln\left(1+x\right)$ up to third order order, since I couldn't use the limit comparison test (implied by Taylor's theorem) with the remainder of the 2nd order expansion. Can you comment about this?

Comment: @Joshhh What was the reason you couldn't use the limit comparison? (I don't see a reason -- may be missing something there). You get $$-\ln\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = \underbrace{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}_{a_n} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}_{b_n}.$$ Now, $\sum_n a_n$ converges by Lipschitz/alternating series criterion, and $\sum_n b_n$ diverges by comparison with the Harmonic series (as $b_n \sim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2n}$).

Comment: @ClementC. From Taylor's theorem, the remainder satisfies $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{R(x)}{x^2} = 0$, letting $x = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$, we have that
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{R\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}} = 0
$$
and therefore the limit comparison test is inconclusive

Comment: @ClementC. Maybe it's just semantics and different definitions we gave at calculus class.

Comment: @Joshhh The two results I am using here are:
(1) the definition of $o(\cdot)$ (Landau notation), which is roughly $f = o(g)$ (at $0$) if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} 0$.

(2) the comparison theorem saying that
"if $(a_n)_n$ is a positive sequence and $(b_n)_n$ satisfies $b_n = a_n + o(a_n)$, then the series $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ have same nature."

Comment: You are of course correct and I have made a silly mistake.

Comment: Well -- if I had one dollar for each silly mistake I have made, I'd probably have suffocated under a mountain of one-dollar bills a long time ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39756/discussion-between-joshhh-and-clement-c).