# Prove $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\right)$ converges if and only if $p>\frac 12$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove that the following sequence converges:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\right)$$
if and only if $p>\frac 12$.

I've seen solutions to this exact problem here, but I am *not* looking for a general solution. I've tried to solve this problem, and could not continue my solution, so I came here to ask for your help on how to continue.

**My solution**

$(\star)$ I have proven that given a sequence $a_n$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, if: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{2n}+a_{2n+1})$ converges *or* diverges to infinity, then $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n$ converges *or* diverges to infinity, respectively.

I have also proven that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\right)$ converges **absolutely** for every $p>1$, converges for $p=1$, and diverges for $p=\frac 12$. So what I have left, essentially, is to prove that the series converges for every $\frac 12<p<1.$

We can see that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{2n}+a_{2n+1})\equiv\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\ln(1+\frac{1}{(2n)^p})+\ln(1-\frac{1}{(2n+1)^p})\right)$$

Since the sequence is negative, we can use the limit test with (after using logarithm rules):

$$\frac{(2n)^p-(2n+1)^p+1}{(4n^2+2n)^p}$$

Now, on the one hand, I don't have the logarithm anymore; But on the other hand, I don't know how to deal with this series. I tried to use the limit test again with $\frac{1}{n^{2p}}$, but to no avail.

I would be very glad to hear how to continue my solution, or rather simplify it. I prefer using the claim I've proven (marked with $(\star)$).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since $\ln\left ( 1+x \right )=x+O\left ( x^2 \right )$ this means that $$\sum_{n\ge 2}\ln\left ( 1+\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^n}{n^p} \right )=\left ( \sum_{n\ge 2}\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^n}{n^p}  \right )+O\left ( \zeta\left ( 2p \right ) \right )$$ which converges when $p > \frac 1 2$ right?

Comment: @EdwardH. I assume this is the Zeta function (though I'm not sure), unfortunately I am not familiar with it

Comment: "Since the sequence is negative." Which sequence?

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541672/9340), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/597060/9340),  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3664560/9340).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your limit test can be made to work.
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{(2x)^p-(2x+1)^p+1}{(4x^2+2x)^p}}{\frac{1}{x^{2p}}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(2x)^p-(2x+1)^p+1}{(4+\frac{2}{x})^p}=\frac{1}{4^p}
$$
Here I used the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}((2x+1)^p-(2x)^p)=0$. You can quickly prove this by noting that $f:x\rightarrow x^p$ is a concave function for $p<1$ ($f''<0$), so you can say that $(2x+1)^p-(2x)^p < 2p(2x)^{p-1}$. But $p-1<0$, so this last expression goes to $0$.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the generalized Bernoulli inequality you have for $0<p\le1$:
$$ \big|(2n)^p-(2n+1)^p+1\big| \le 1+ (2n)^p \big((1+\frac{1}{2n})^p- 1\big) \le 1+ (2n)^p\frac{p}{2n}$$
You have then
$$ \left|\frac{(2n)^p-(2n+1)^p+1}{(4n^2 + 2n)^p}\right| \le \frac{1+ p(2n)^{p-1}}{(2n)^{2p}(1+\frac{1}{2n})^p} $$
$(2n)^{p-1} \rightarrow 0$, so by comparison test, the series is convergent for $p>\frac12$.