# A very strange series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> For which value of $p\in\mathbb{R}$ does the series
> $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln \left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\right)$$ converge
> (and absolutely converge)?

My attempt:
For $p\leq 0$, the series diverges, so it diverges absolutely. We just need to consider the case $p>0$.
$\ln \left(1+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\right)=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^p}-\dfrac{1}{2n^{2p}}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{2p}}\right)$.
We know $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^p}$ converges according to Leibniz criterion.
If $p>\dfrac{1}{2}$ then $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2n^{2p}}, \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{2p}}\right) $ converges. So when $p>\dfrac{1}{2}$, the given series converges. I don't know whether it converges absolutely or not in this case and still have no idea to deal with $p\leq\dfrac{1}{2}$. Can someone else continue?

Comment: An infinite product may help here.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: For $n=1$ the term is $\ln(0)$.

Comment: Ok, let n run from 2

Comment: If you exponentiate the sum to get exp(), you get a product, enabling you to use what is known about infinite products.

Comment: When I saw your series, it was just like deja vu. Yes, I remember right. Three years ago, I answer the question with the same series which was asked for convergence/divergence.

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541672/9340), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/597060/9340), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3239056/9340),  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3664560/9340).

Answer (score 1):

Note the following easy observations:

> **Observation.** Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be sequences in $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> 1. If $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally and $\sum b_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ converges conditionally.
> 2. If $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum b_n$ diverges, then $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ diverges.
>
> Each of the statements can be proved by considering its contrapositive.

Returning to OP's problem, let $ f(x) = \log(1 + x) - x$ and note that $f(x) \sim -\frac{1}{2}x^2$ as $x \to 0$. Also, let $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}$ for simplicity.

**Case 1.** If $p \in (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, then $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \log(1+a_n)$ converges absolutely by the limit comparison with the $p$-series $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$.

**Case 2.** If $p \in (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, then

- $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n $ converges by the alternating series test,
- $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} |a_n| $ diverges by the limit comparison test with the $p$-series $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$, and
- $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f(a_n)$ converges absolutely by the limit comparison test with the $p$-series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{2p}}$.

Therefore $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \log(1+a_n)$ converges conditionally.

**Case 3.** If $p \in (0, \frac{1}{2}]$, then

- $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n $ converges by the alternating series test, and
- $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f(a_n)$ diverges to $-\infty$ by the limit comparison test with the $p$-series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{2p}}$.

Therefore $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \log(1+a_n)$ diverges to $-\infty$.